# Why does NGINX reverse proxy $.ajax post give "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: ajax, post, nginx, proxy, reverse

I get "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when waiting for xhr response. 
I have tried using the api directy and it works fine. I recieve my responses. Also when using it through nginx reverse proxy my api actually recieves the POST, but jquery doesn't get anything back. Like I said, it does when using http://ip:port..

My nginx config lookes like this:

```
upstream daffy {
    server 127.0.0.1:4747;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name daffy;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/daffy.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/daffy.error.log;

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://daffy/socket.io;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /git/pull/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://daffy;
    }

    location / {
        allow   192.168.7.0/24;
        deny    all;

        proxy_pass http://daffy;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Nginx shows no errors in error log.. but access log does not register the POST request at all.

nginx-1.11.12-1.el7.ngx.x86_64

does anyone have a suggestion?

**UPDATE**
I have tried disabling firewall and turned on debug in my error log.

Nginx doesn't really provide anything in error log with debug on.

But GET is working just fine:

```
192.168.7.114 - - [02/Apr/2017:09:54:02 +0200] "GET /users/?_=1491119642698 HTTP/1.1" 200 570 "http://daffy/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

SELinux is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!**

I had to change my python backend to return a bit faster than 2 seconds:

```
Popen(["/path/to/awesome.sh"], stdin=None,stdout=None,stderr=None)
```

Before I was using `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.call`

Anyway, I cut of 2 seconds of the return from api :)